# Все фоны в одной картинке

Tags: html, css

Копаясь в кодах чужих сайтов, не раз встречал картинки, на которых объединены фоновые изображения для разных элементов(например, разноцветные кнопки). Например вот как эта http://www.webmolot.com/i/menu_sprite.png

Не подскажете, как это достигается? Можно ссылкой на какую-нибудь статью по этому поводу, или поисковым запросом=)

Дополнение: под словом "это" имею ввиду стили, указывающие, какую именно часть картинки использовать для конкретного элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется sprite. [Гуглим](https://www.google.com.ua/search?source=ig&rlz=1G1GGLQ_RUUA374&q=css+sprite+button&oq=css+sprite+button&gs_l=igoogle.3..0l2j0i30l8.1034.14193.0.15409.32.21.6.5.5.0.163.2082.0j19.19.0...0.0...1ac.1.k-lDOLAIi20))

Comment: По нескольким причинам, принимаю этот ответ)

Answer (score 1):

[CSS спрайты](http://html-css.info/2009/07/css-sprites/) - первая ссылка в гугле. width, height, background-position решает.

Answer (score 0):

Берешь этот спрайт и в нужном месте просто меняешь позицию показа относительно того HTML элемента где нужно вывести нужную картинку из спрайта.

1. Грузится только 1 картинка
2. Разместить можно много картинок на нем